# Missing titles in Google Docs table of contents

Tags: google-docs

I'm facing a problem with a document in Google Docs.

I've set different styles for my title and headings because I'd like to automatically generate the table of contents.

After setting "Example of Title" as a "Title", "Example of heading1" as "Heading 1" and "Example of heading2" as "Heading 2", I've tried to insert **TOC** and it appears but it shows only heading1 and heading2.

[image]

So my title is not shown in TOC and I don't understand why. Do you know why?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I believe this is because the Title is not intended to be used in the table of contents, I'm curious myself as to what purpose you would have it serve? My recommendation is to place the title of the document above the Table of Contents simply because it makes more sense chronologically.

Comment: @Passer-By I've applied the "title" style to every chapter title of my document. Now I've applied "heading1" style to every chapter and it works. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Title" style is not intended to be used in the Table of Contents, so I've changed styles in my document and I've only used Heading1, Heading2, Heading3 and so on.

Comment: lame, in Microsoft word you can customize it so you can use title.